# amp-accordion link to section header

Tags: hyperlink, menu, amp-html

In an AMP page menu, we have some sections with out any children. In this case we would like to link to the section header directly. We could not do this. Any help/pointers in this area would be greatly appreciated. For example, in the following code, would like to link to "Nested Section 2.1", clicking on which should take to the target page directly (and not open the section).

```
<amp-accordion>
<section>
  <h4>Section 1</h4>
  <p>Bunch of content.</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h4>Section 2</h4>
  <amp-accordion class="nested-accordion">
    <section>
      <h4>Nested Section 2.1</h4>
      <p>Bunch of content.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4>Nested Section 2.2</h4>
      <p>Bunch of more content.</p>
    </section>
  </amp-accordion>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually know very little about AMP pages and still trying to learn more about it but based from the [AMP's official documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-accordion),`amp-accordion`'s behavior are the following:

> - An amp-accordion can contain one or more `<section>`s as its direct children.
> - **Each `<section>` must contain exactly two direct children**.
> - The first child (of the section) must be one of h1, h2, ..., h6, header, and is the heading of the section.
> - The second child (of the section) can be any tag allowed in AMP HTML and is the content of the section.
> - **Clicking/tapping on the heading of a section expands/ or collapses the section**.

You may want to also check [10 Important Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) Components You Should Know](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/important-amp-components/) for helpful insights.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't place these sections into an accordion and match their style to the accordion headers, e.g.:

```
<amp-accordion>
<section>
  <h4>Section 1</h4>
  <p>Bunch of content.</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h4>Section 2</h4>

  <div>
    <h4><a href="...">Nested Section 2.1</a></h4>
    <amp-accordion class="nested-accordion">
      <section>
        <h4>Nested Section 2.2</h4>
        <p>Bunch of more content.</p>
      </section>
    </amp-accordion>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<amp-accordion>
    <section>
        <h4>Section 1</h4>
        <p>Bunch of content.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
        </header>
        <p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header>
            <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>    
        </header>
        <p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h4>Section 2</h4>
        <amp-accordion class="nested-accordion">
           <section>
               <h4>Nested Section 2.1</h4>
               <p>Bunch of content.</p>
          </section>
          <section>
              <h4>Nested Section 2.2</h4>
              <p>Bunch of more content.</p>
         </section>
     </amp-accordion>
</section>
```